# The number of monochromatic triangles

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, graph-colorings, ramsey-theory, extremal-graph-theory

It is well known that the minimum number of monochromatic triangles in a red/blue coloring of the edges of the complete graph $K_n$ is given by Goodman's formula
$$M(n)=\binom n3-\left\lfloor\frac n2\left\lfloor\left(\frac{n-1}2\right)^2\right\rfloor\right\rfloor;$$
see OEIS sequence [A014557](http://oeis.org/A014557) or the original paper by A. W. Goodman, [On sets of acquaintances and strangers at any party](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2310464?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), Amer. Math. Monthly 66 (1959), 778–783, or my answer to [this math.stackexchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2216943/counting-triangles-in-a-graph-or-its-complement).

> Is there any literature on the more general question, what is the minimum number of monochromatic triangles in a red/blue coloring of the edges of the complete graph $K_n$ **with a prescribed number of edges of each color?**

...

> Is there any literature on the related question, given natural numbers $n$ and $k$, what is the minimum value of the quantity $m+kb$ over all red/blue colorings of the edges of the complete graph $K_n$, where $m$ is the number of monochromatic triangles (of either color) and $b$ is the number of blue edges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are results, obtained via integer linear programming, for the first question for $n \le 10$ and $b$ blue edges, where $b \le \binom{n}{2}/2$:
\begin{matrix}
n\backslash b & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 \\
\hline
2 & 0 \\
3 & 1 & 0 \\
4 & 4 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
5 & 10 & 7 & 4 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
6 & 20 & 16 & 12 & 8 & 6 & 4 & 2 & 2 \\
7 & 35 & 30 & 25 & 20 & 16 & 13 & 10 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 4 \\
8 & 56 & 50 & 44 & 38 & 32 & 28 & 24 & 20 & 16 & 14 & 12 & 10 & 8 & 8 & 8 \\
9 & 84 & 77 & 70 & 63 & 56 & 50 & 45 & 40 & 35 & 30 & 27 & 24 & 21 & 18 & 16 & 15 & 14 & 13 & 12 \\
10 & 120 & 112 & 104 & 96 & 88 & 80 & 74 & 68 & 62 & 56 & 50 & 46 & 42 & 38 & 34 & 30 & 28 & 26 & 24 & 22 & 20 & 20 & 20 \\
\end{matrix}

And here are results for the second question:
\begin{matrix}
n\backslash k & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
\hline
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
3 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
4 & 0 & 2 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\
5 & 0 & 5 & 8 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 \\
6 & 2 & 8 & 14 & 17 & 20 & 20 & 20 & 20 & 20 & 20 & 20 \\ 
7 & 4 & 14 & 21 & 28 & 32 & 35 & 35 & 35 & 35 & 35 & 35 \\ 
8 & 8 & 20 & 32 & 40 & 48 & 52 & 56 & 56 & 56 & 56 & 56 \\ 
9 & 12 & 30 & 44 & 57 & 66 & 75 & 80 & 84 & 84 & 84 & 84 \\ 
10 & 20 & 40 & 60 & 75 & 90 & 100 & 110 & 115 & 120 & 120 & 120 \\
\end{matrix}
For $k=0$, the minimum is $m+0=M(n)$.  For large enough $k$, all edges are red, yielding $m=\binom{n}{3}$ and $b=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that the red degree of each vertex is denoted by $r_x$, and the total number of red edges is $R=\frac{1}{2}\sum_x r_x$. Then the number of monochromatic triangles is exactly
$$ \binom{n}{3}-(n-1)R+\frac{1}{2}\sum_xr_x^2.$$

The minimum value can be derived from this, but the answer will be a little messy according as $2R$ is divisible by $n$ or not. If $2R$ is divisible by $n$, the minimum this can be is when all the $r_x$ are equal (so $=2R/n$), and so for example in this case the minimum number of monochromatic triangles is

$$ \binom{n}{3}-(n-1)R+\frac{2R^2}{n}.$$

(Note this is indeed attainable by taking red edges to be a regular graph. Also this is always a lower bound for the number of monochromatic triangles by Cauchy-Schwarz, but will not be achievable if $R$ is not divisible by $n$.)

The first formula is just a rearrangement of Goodman's more general formula, which says that for all coloured $K_n$ the number of monochromatic triangles is equal to

$$ \frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_x \binom{r_x}{2}+\sum_x\binom{n-1-r_x}{2}-\binom{n}{3}\right).$$

(The proof of which is just to note that if we count all monochromatic pairs of edges from each vertex then each monochromatic triangle is counted 3 times and non-monochromatic triangles are counted once.)

Comment: In general case $r_x$'s should be almost equal (every two differ at most by 1). This is also achievable.